# split datetime periods by null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I want to split up the data period  by null values.
Suppose that I've got table like this.

```
Date                |  abc
2016-04-18 07:10:00 | 2.3
2016-04-18 07:20:00 | 2.1
2016-04-18 07:30:00 |
2016-04-18 07:40:00 | 
2016-05-01 10:00:00 | 1.9
2016-05-01 10:10:00 | 4.5
2016-05-01 10:20:00 | 3.9
```

Some abc column data are `null` and the date column interval is 10 minutes.

I want to make date period split up by null values of abc.

Result

```
      start                     end 
2016-04-18 07:10:00 ~ 2016-04-18 07:20:00 
2016-05-01 10:00:00 ~ 2016-05-01 10:20:00
```

Answer (score 1):

"Gaps And Islands" problems are typically solved by applying a window function that checks for changes in the data and assigning a group number based on those changes.

To start, one needs to compare the current value with the previous value based on the sort order defined by the timestamp column:

This statement:

```
select *,
       case
          when abc is null or lag(abc) over (order by "date") is not null then null
          else 1
        end as group_flag
from data
order by "date";
```

Returns this result:

```
date                | abc | group_flag
--------------------+-----+-----------
2016-04-18 07:10:00 | 2.3 |          1
2016-04-18 07:20:00 | 2.1 |           
2016-04-18 07:30:00 |     |           
2016-04-18 07:40:00 |     |          
2016-05-01 10:00:00 | 1.9 |          1
2016-05-01 10:10:00 | 4.5 |           
2016-05-01 10:20:00 | 3.9 |
```

As you can see, we get a flag each time a new "group" starts.

The next step is to use a running sum, to change the "flag" into actual groups:

```
select *,
       sum(group_flag) over (order by date) as group_nr
from (
  select *,
         case
            when abc is null lag(abc) over (order by "date") is not null then null
            else 1
          end as group_flag
  from data
) t1
order by "date";
```

This returns:

```
date                | abc | group_flag | group_nr
--------------------+-----+------------+---------
2016-04-18 07:10:00 | 2.3 |          1 |        1
2016-04-18 07:20:00 | 2.1 |            |        1
2016-04-18 07:30:00 |     |            |        1
2016-04-18 07:40:00 |     |            |        1
2016-05-01 10:00:00 | 1.9 |          1 |        2
2016-05-01 10:10:00 | 4.5 |            |        2
2016-05-01 10:20:00 | 3.9 |            |        2
```

As you can see, the new column `group_nr` now identifies the consecutive periods we are interested in. For your result we just need to filter out those rows where `abc` is null:

```
select min(date) as period_start, max(date) as period_end
from (
    select *,
           sum(group_flag) over (order by date) as group_nr
    from (
      select *,
             case
                when abc is null or lag(abc) over (order by date) is not null then null
                else 1
              end as group_flag
      from data
    ) t1
    order by "date"
) t2
where abc is not null
group by group_nr;
```

This returns:

```
period_start        | period_end         
--------------------+--------------------
2016-04-18 07:10:00 | 2016-04-18 07:20:00
2016-05-01 10:40:00 | 2016-05-01 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more readable solution using CTEs and avoiding nested queries.

I'm not sure what behaviour you expect in case of the same Date appears for NULL and NOT NULL abc value. Do you want to exclude NULL from data set in this case?

```
-- Only if your server supports LAG and LEAD windowed functions
-- See alternative BeginEndFlagedSet below
WITH BeginEndFlagedSet as
(
    SELECT
        Date,
        Abc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date ASC) as Num,
        CASE 
            WHEN Abc IS NOT NULL AND LAG(Abc) OVER(ORDER BY Date) IS NULL THEN 'Start'
            WHEN Abc IS NOT NULL AND LEAD(Abc) OVER(ORDER BY Date) IS NULL THEN 'End'
        END as BeginEndFlag
    FROM [YourTable]
)
SELECT 
    MIN(StartRow.Date) as "Start Date",
    CASE 
        WHEN MIN(CASE EndRow.BeginEndFlag WHEN 'End' THEN EndRow.Date END) 
            > MIN(CASE EndRow.BeginEndFlag WHEN 'Start' THEN EndRow.Date END) THEN MIN(StartRow.Date)
        WHEN MIN(CASE EndRow.BeginEndFlag WHEN 'End' THEN EndRow.Date END) IS NULL THEN MIN(StartRow.Date)
        ELSE MIN(CASE EndRow.BeginEndFlag WHEN 'End' THEN EndRow.Date END)
    END as "End Date"
FROM BeginEndFlagedSet StartRow
LEFT JOIN BeginEndFlagedSet EndRow on 
    StartRow.Num < EndRow.Num 
    and EndRow.BeginEndFlag in ('Start', 'End') 
WHERE StartRow.BeginEndFlag = 'Start'
GROUP BY StartRow.Num
```

At first step we assign numbers to each row:

<kbd>**`Date`**</kbd>               <kbd>**`Abc`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Num`**</kbd>
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:10:00`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:20:00`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:30:00`</kbd><kbd>`NULL`</kbd><kbd>`3`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:40:00`</kbd><kbd>`NULL`</kbd><kbd>`4`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:00:00`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`5`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:10:00`</kbd><kbd>`5`</kbd>   <kbd>`6`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:20:00`</kbd><kbd>`4`</kbd>   <kbd>`7`</kbd>

Then compare each row is this set to previous and following values:

<kbd>**`Date`**</kbd>               <kbd>**`Abc`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Num`**</kbd> <kbd>**`LAG(Abc)`**</kbd> <kbd>**`LEAD(Abc)`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Flag`**</kbd> 
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:10:00`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`1`</kbd>   <kbd>`NULL`</kbd>     <kbd>`2`</kbd>         <kbd>`Start`</kbd>
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:20:00`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>        <kbd>`NULL`</kbd>      <kbd>`End`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:30:00`</kbd><kbd>`NULL`</kbd><kbd>`3`</kbd>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>        <kbd>`NULL`</kbd>           
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:40:00`</kbd><kbd>`NULL`</kbd><kbd>`4`</kbd>   <kbd>`NULL`</kbd>     <kbd>`2`</kbd>              
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:00:00`</kbd><kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`5`</kbd>   <kbd>`NULL`</kbd>     <kbd>`5`</kbd>         <kbd>`Start`</kbd>
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:10:00`</kbd><kbd>`5`</kbd>   <kbd>`6`</kbd>   <kbd>`2`</kbd>        <kbd>`4`</kbd>              
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:20:00`</kbd><kbd>`4`</kbd>   <kbd>`7`</kbd>   <kbd>`5`</kbd>        <kbd>`NULL`</kbd>      <kbd>`End`</kbd>

At the end we are looking for corresponding end-flagged Date for each start-flagged Date:

<kbd>**`Start Date`**</kbd>               <kbd>**`End Date`**</kbd>       
<kbd>`2016-04-18 07:10:00.000`</kbd><kbd>`2016-04-18 07:20:00.000`</kbd>
<kbd>`2016-05-01 10:00:00.000`</kbd><kbd>`2016-05-01 10:20:00.000`</kbd>

Alternative BeginEndFlagedSet in case if your server does not support LAG and LEAD windowed functions (as mine):

```
WITH NumberedSet as
(
    SELECT 
        Date, 
        Abc, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date ASC) as Num
    FROM [YourTable]
)
, BeginEndFlagedSet as
(
    SELECT
        This.Num,
        This.Date,
        This.Abc,
        CASE 
            WHEN This.Abc IS NOT NULL AND Prev.Abc IS NULL THEN 'Start'
            WHEN This.Abc IS NOT NULL AND Next.Abc IS NULL THEN 'End'
        END as BeginEndFlag
    FROM NumberedSet as This
    LEFT JOIN NumberedSet as Prev 
        on This.Num = Prev.Num + 1
    LEFT JOIN NumberedSet as Next 
        on This.Num = Next.Num - 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @a_horse_with_no_name